# Closing a GStreamer RTSP server that is running on a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, gstreamer, rtsp

I have written a program that creates an RTSP server on a thread. I thought that by simply quitting the loop which the RTSP server is running on (i.e. `g_main_loop_quit(loop)`), the server will close by itself and terminate any existing connections but that did not appear to be the case.

I use VLC player to preview the RTSP stream and I noticed that when the server thread exits (while main is still running), the VLC player is still able to receive transmission from the server. If I close the player, I'm not able to connect to the server again. What am I not 'unref'ing or freeing that is keeping the server alive?

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int thread_running = 1;

struct ThreadArgs {
    GMainLoop *loop;
};

void *ServerThreadFunction(void *args) {
    g_print("Starting server.\n");

    ThreadArgs *ta = (ThreadArgs *)args;    
    GstRTSPServer *server;
    GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;
    GstRTSPMountPoints *mounts;

    gst_init(NULL, NULL);

    server = gst_rtsp_server_new();
    gst_rtsp_server_attach(server, NULL);

    factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new();
    gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory, "( videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0 )");

    mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points(server);
    gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory(mounts, "/test", factory);
    g_object_unref(mounts);

    g_main_loop_run(ta->loop);

    g_object_unref(server);
    g_print("Terminating server.\n");
    thread_running = 0;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *KillServerFunction(void *args) {
    ThreadArgs *ta = (ThreadArgs *)args;
    cout << "Is the loop running? " << g_main_loop_is_running(ta->loop) << endl;
    g_main_loop_quit(ta->loop);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ThreadArgs *ta = new ThreadArgs;
    ta->loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    pthread_t server_thread;
    int rc = pthread_create(&server_thread, NULL, ServerThreadFunction, (void *)ta);

    // Start VLC player here e.g. vlc rtsp://127.0.0.1/test

    sleep(1);
    cout << "Killing server in 3" << endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout << "Killing server in 2" << endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout << "Killing server in 1" << endl;
    sleep(1);

    pthread_t kill_server_thread;
    pthread_create(&kill_server_thread, NULL, KillServerFunction, (void *)ta);

    while (thread_running == 1) {}
    cout << "Program continues to run but stream is still viewable on VLC player..." << endl;
    sleep(100);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about sending EOS to the pipe? maybe [this one](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPMediaFactory.html#gst-rtsp-media-factory-set-eos-shutdown)

Comment: @otopolsky I've enabled gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_eos_shutdown (factory, TRUE) and I guess I need to set the eos-shutdown property to TRUE to send EOS down the pipeline. I'm a very new to GLib so I'm not sure how to set the property of the factory element. I used `g_object_set (factory, "eos-shutdown", TRUE, NULL)` just before the thread ends but nothing appears to be different.

Comment: I thought that caling gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_eos_shutdown would be enough.. what about G_OBJECT(factory) ?

Comment: @otopolsky I think that function only sets whether the factory can be EOS'ed. `"Configure if media created from this factory will have an EOS sent to the pipeline before shutdown"`. The EOS still needs to be sent to the pipeline and I've no idea how. G_OBJECT(factory) does not make any difference btw.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

Need to call **g_source_remove();**

**Creating server:**

```
if ((gst_server_id=gst_rtsp_server_attach (gst_server, NULL)) == 0)
    goto failed;
```

**Stopping server:**

```
 g_source_remove (gst_server_id);
```

Also, From [gstreamer-rtsp-server docs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPServer.html#gst-rtsp-server-attach):

> Note that **if context is not the default main context** as returned by
>   g_main_context_default() (or NULL), g_source_remove() cannot be used
>   to destroy the source. In that case it is recommended to use
>   gst_rtsp_server_create_source() and attach it to context manually.